# Extending Working holiday visa to Work visa

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card, working-holiday-visas

I'm currently in Germany on a working holiday visa, and have received a job offer, for which I need a work visa/blue card. Since it's impossible to get an appointment at the Auslandebehorde any time soon, I'm looking for ways to start working ASAP.

I remember reading recently on a forum (can't find the link now unfortunately) about someone who managed to extend/change their working holiday/language visa to a temporary working visa, on which they could legally work, until they got their blue card.

I was wondering if anyone can confirm, or has had a similar experience?

bonus question: is it possible to work full time on my WHV until I get my blue card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with many institutions, many emails & phone calls: yes it is possible to go from WHV to Working visa/Blue card.

Also, it is possible and perfectly legal to work on a WHV, no restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "temporary working visa", but for most nationalities it is possible to change the working holiday visa to a Blue Card / Employment Visa.

You can generally work full time on the Working Holiday Visa, but some restrictions apply depending on your nationality. For more details I'd have to know your nationality, when your visa was issues, what you have been working so far.