# Working holiday visa restrictions

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card, working-holiday-visas

does anyone know, or could point me in the right direction, about the restrictions of working on a Work holiday visa in germany, regarding:

- hours
- salary
- contract

I'm currently on a WHV, got a job offer and looking to get a blue card. Is it legally acceptable for me to work for about a month, until I get my blue card?

This isn't a "summer" job, it's a software developer job, I'd be earning a decent amount. Am I allowed to work on a WHV, of course with paying full taxes etc?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/extending-working-holiday-visa-to-work-visa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with several institutions & many many emails, phone calls and live appointments: working on WHV is perfectly legal, there are no restrictions. The only thing they make trouble with is that it's not "in the spirit of the WHV" to work full time (you *should* travel and take up odd jobs), but "in the spirit of" has no legal basis.